# Fastest method for copy list box Items to a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, richtextbox

So far i am using the following code to move the items of a list box to a `RichText box`.

```
  For k As Integer = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1   
      RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & ListBox.Items(k) & vbNewLine
  Next
```

The problem here is that when i use like this the code take around `2`minutes for moving `5000` items. is their any fastest method for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a string to be added beforehand.

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For Each item In ListBox.Items
    sb.AppendLine(item.ToString())
Next

RichTextBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString())
```